# Proving that a complex function is not differentiable anywhere

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show from the definition of the derivative that $f(z) = Re(z)$ is not complex differentiable at any point.

Easy with the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I need to do it a different way. Here's my solution, which is convincing enough for me, but there seems to be a subtlety at the end...

Let $z=x+iy$. Then by definition, $f'(z)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$. If this limit exists, it must exist independently of the direction in which $h$ approaches $0$.

Let $h\to0$ along the real axis. Then $z+h=(x+h)+iy$, so $f(z+h)=x+h$. Thus we have $$f'(z)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{x+h-x}{h}=1$$

Now let $h\to0$ along the imaginary axis. Then $z+h=x+i(y+h)$, so $f(z+h)=x$. Hence $$f'(z)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{x-x}{h}=\frac{0}{0}$$ Here is where I'm unsure of myself. Originally I said $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined, and so is certainly not equal to $1$, but I thought about L'hospital's rule, and it seems more appropriate to call $\frac{0}{0}$ "indeterminate".

Anyway, is it alright to claim that $1 \neq \frac{0}{0}$? And if so, is my reasoning correct for this proof?

Comment: The limit is just $0$ not $0/0$. It would however not be alright to claim that $1 \neq 0/0$. The rest is fine as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last limit is $0$, it is not indeterminate.

An indeterminate form arise when you have two functions that *tend* to $0$ and you take their quotient; I think it is important to understand that what this "indeterminate" form tells you is that you don't have enough *information* to understand if the limit is $0$, $\infty$, or any other constant.

Indeterminate forms are just a lack of information; in fact, through manipulations (hopital, taylor expansion, etc) you can usually *find* the result; simply, it is not apparent because the $0/0$ expression tells you nothing about what really happens.

In this case though you have $0/h$. Now, for every $h$, this *number* is clearly equal to $0$; and $$\lim_{h \to 0} 0 = 0$$

The rest of the proof is correct

Answer (score 1):

Let me show you an alternative solution.

Do the limit approach through a path $h=h_x+ikh_x$:
$$
f'(z)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{x+h_x-x}{h_x+ikh_x}=\lim\limits_{h_x \to 0}\frac{h_x}{h_x+ikh_x}=\frac{1}{1+ik}
$$

Since this value will depend on the approach path, the limit is indeterminate, i.e. the limit does not exist, then the derivative does not exist.